# C# parallel return value

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, aggregation

I use the following code to attempt to do a few calculations using values from two separate arrays.  I've been trying to aggregate a list of values as a final step but every time I run the program it only has one set of values in the list.  abcXLoopVars is a custom class to store the different variables which I aggregate later.

```
Parallel.For<abcXLoopVars>(0, colX.Count(),
            () => { return new abcXLoopVars(); },
            (i, pls, state) =>
        {
            state = new abcXLoopVars();
            double x = Math.Abs(colX[i]);
            double y =   Math.Abs(colY[i]);
            double lnx = Math.Log(x);
            double lny = Math.Log(y);
            double xminxbarsq = Math.Pow(colX[i] - xbar, 2);
            double xminxbarcub = Math.Pow(colX[i] - xbar, 4);
            state.sumxminxbarsq = xminxbarsq;
            state.sumxminxbarcub = xminxbarcub;
            state.sumlnxxminxbarsq = lnx * xminxbarsq;
            state.sumlnxlny = lnx * lny;
            state.sumlnxsq = Math.Pow(lnx, 2);
            state.sumlnx = sumlnx + lnx;
            state.sumlnyxminxbarsq = lny * xminxbarsq;
            state.sumlny = lny;
            state.posneg = colY[i] / colX[i];

            return state;
        },
        (state) => { lock (lockMe) abxList.Add(state);}
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to rewrite it as PLINQ:

```
    colX.Zip(colY, (x, y) =>
        {
            var state = new abcXLoopVars();
            double lnx = Math.Log(x);
            double lny = Math.Log(y);
            double xminxbarsq = Math.Pow(x - xbar, 2);
            double xminxbarcub = Math.Pow(x - xbar, 4);
            state.sumxminxbarsq = xminxbarsq;
            state.sumxminxbarcub = xminxbarcub;
            state.sumlnxxminxbarsq = lnx * xminxbarsq;
            state.sumlnxlny = lnx * lny;
            state.sumlnxsq = Math.Pow(lnx, 2);
            state.sumlnx = sumlnx + lnx;
            state.sumlnyxminxbarsq = lny * xminxbarsq;
            state.sumlny = lny;
            state.posneg = y / x;

            return state;
        }).AsParallel().ToList();
```

Comment: You should call `.AsParallel()` before `.Zip()` in order to apply some parallelism to your query, otherwise (as in your case) query will execute sequentially. Also you should call `.AsParallel()` on `colY`, before passing it to `.Zip()`, otherwise an exception is thrown.